# Where can I find a list of *all* MIPS registers?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

The [standard MIPS reference sheet](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) I see everywhere only lists the main 32 registers. But I also know that there's 32 floating point registers associated with coprocessor 1, and the registers of coprocessor 0. There may be others I'm not aware of. Is there a single place that lists *all* the MIPS registers?

Answer (score 2):

Screen shots taken from MARS IDE.

[image: Regular registers]

[image: Coproc 1 registers]

[image: Coproc 0 registers]

Comment: Thanks, that works. So for coprocessor 0, why doesn't it show the other registers?

Comment: I guess these are all registers available for coproc 0.

Comment: The full coprocessor 0 register list can be found in [MIPS32 Architecture for Programmers Volume III](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2012sp/MIPS_Vol3.pdf). MARS/SPIM just doesn't implement all of them.